# How do I disallow viewing of files with certain extensions in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

We serve up our pages with Apache 2.2 on Windows.  We'd like to disallow viewing of pages with the .txt extension.  How can we do something like that?

Another option which would arguably be even better would be to have a list of filetypes that are allowed to be served statically.

Ideas?

Just FYI: My original issue was mostly just because my file regex was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://www.ducea.com/2006/07/21/apache-tips-tricks-deny-access-to-certain-file-types

hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, this is for apache 1.3 and 2.0.  This won't work for 2.2

Comment: Did actually you test that Frew? This works for me on Apache 2.2.9.

Comment: Yeah, I tested it, it just seems to show the files just fine :-/

Comment: Frew: no offense, but you're doing something wrong.  It works.

Comment: @KPWINC: it works perfecly even under Apache 2.2.19, thank you so much for sharing such an interesting link, and obviously +1